# Change opacity after fields are filled

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, events, dom-events

I currently have a child's image which when clicked will show the child's form fields (name & birthday). I also have a father's image which when clicked will show the father's form fields (name & birthday). I have made the father's image opacity 50%, which when clicked will alert the users that they have to complete the child's field first and if the users have already completed the child's fields, the father's fields will be shown.

However, I want that when the user has input all of the child's form fields, the father's image's opacity will automatically be 100% (indicating that the user can now fill in father's details). Do I need to use custom event? I am trying to use jQuery here. Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

Comment: `blur` of your `input` items would probably help here. Unless you're using jQuery validation.

Comment: @mattytommo how can blur help in this scenario?

Comment: Attach the `blur` event to your input boxes, check it's value (and the values of the other fields on the form). If they all have (valid) values, then set the opacity of the father image.

Comment: @mattytommo it actually works! thanks for the suggestion! I was focusing on making custom event, did not think about this before.

Comment: No problems, I've added it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments:

The simplest solution here is to attach the `blur` event to your input boxes, check it's value (and the values of the other fields on the form). If they all have (valid) values, then set the opacity of the father image. Something like:

```
$("input").on("blur", function () { 
    //check all input values, as well as this one
    if (valid) {
       //set opacity to your image
    }
});
```